# inflateexeption : binary xml file line 31 (use patternview in overlyview)

Tags: android, xml, view

sorry for my bad English .
i want to use pattern view in my overly view .

```
public class PatternOverlayView extends OverlayView implements PatternView.OnPatternListener{

private CameraGestureSensor mGestureSensor;
private boolean mOpenCVInitiated = false;

 private final static String FORMAT_12_HOURS = "hh:mm";
 private final static String FORMAT_24_HOURS = "kk:mm";
private String mTimeFormat;
private String mDateFormat;
private Calendar mCalendar;
private String mAM, mPM;
private String mDayFormat;
private String moFormat;
NumberPicker np,np1,np2 ;
static TextView tim;
static TextView month;
static TextView dayt;
static TextView salt;
static TextView roozt;
static TextView chargelevel;
static TextView am;
private static final String TAG = "PracticeGesturesActivity";
//private Direction mCurrentDirection;
SharedPreferences getload ;
Activity Acti ;
RelativeLayout ivLoader ;
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
private GestureDetector mGesture;
 RelativeLayout topvi ;
 private static final String KEY_NUM_FAILED_ATTEMPTS = "num_failed_attempts";

 protected TextView messageText;
    protected PatternView patternView;
    protected LinearLayout buttonContainer;
    protected Button leftButton;
    protected Button rightButton;


    protected int numFailedAttempts;
public PatternOverlayView(Bestservice service,Activity ac,View vi) {

    super(service, R.layout.patternlock, 1,ac,vi);

    Acti = ac ;

    /**Window window = ac.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    */

}

public int getGravity() {
    return Gravity.TOP + Gravity.RIGHT;
}











@Override
public void onPatternStart() {

    removeClearPatternRunnable();

    // Set display mode to correct to ensure that pattern can be in stealth mode.
    patternView.setDisplayMode(PatternView.DisplayMode.Correct);
}

@Override
public void onPatternCellAdded(List<PatternView.Cell> pattern) {}

@Override
public void onPatternDetected(List<PatternView.Cell> pattern) {
    if (isPatternCorrect(pattern)) {
        onConfirmed();
    } else {
        //messageText.setText(R.string.pl_wrong_pattern);
        patternView.setDisplayMode(PatternView.DisplayMode.Wrong);
        postClearPatternRunnable();
        //ViewAccessibilityCompat.announceForAccessibility(messageText, messageText.getText());
        onWrongPattern();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPatternCleared() {
    removeClearPatternRunnable();
}

protected boolean isStealthModeEnabled() {
    return false;
}

protected boolean isPatternCorrect(List<PatternView.Cell> pattern) {
    return true;
}

protected void onConfirmed() {
  //  setResult(RESULT_OK);
  //  finish();
}

protected void onWrongPattern() {
   // ++numFailedAttempts;
}

protected void onCancel() {
   // setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
   // finish();
}

protected void onForgotPassword() {
   // setResult(RESULT_FORGOT_PASSWORD);
   // finish();
}
 private final Runnable clearPatternRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // clearPattern() resets display mode to DisplayMode.Correct.
            patternView.clearPattern();
        }
    };

 protected void removeClearPatternRunnable() {
        patternView.removeCallbacks(clearPatternRunnable);
    }

    protected void postClearPatternRunnable() {
        removeClearPatternRunnable();
        patternView.postDelayed(clearPatternRunnable, 2000);
    }
private void endoflock()
{
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
     // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
     v.vibrate(300);
    Activity ac = serializ.activity;
    ac.finish();
    if (getload.getBoolean("animstatuse", false) == true)
    frameAnimation.stop();

    //getContext().stopService(new Intent(UpdateService.ACTION_UPDATE));

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SampleOverlayHideActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onInflateView() {

      messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pl_message_text);
        patternView = (PatternView)findViewById(R.id.pl_pattern);
        buttonContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pl_button_container);
        leftButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pl_left_button);
        rightButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pl_right_button);
    messageText.setText(R.string.pl_draw_pattern_to_unlock);
    patternView.setInStealthMode(isStealthModeEnabled());
    patternView.setOnPatternListener(this);
    leftButton.setText(R.string.pl_cancel);
    leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onCancel();
        }
    });
    rightButton.setText(R.string.pl_forgot_pattern);
    rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onForgotPassword();
        }
    });
    ViewAccessibilityCompat.announceForAccessibility(messageText, messageText.getText());






    OnTouchListener swiplisen = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return  mGesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
    };

/**  
     tim = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.time);
     tim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            endoflock();
        }
    });
     month = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Date);
     dayt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day);
     salt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sal);
     roozt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rooz);
     am = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AM_PM);
     chargelevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.chargetext);
     getContext().startService(new Intent(UpdateService.ACTION_UPDATE));

    setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
 //  np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
 //   np1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2); 
 //    np2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);
 //    np.setMaxValue(9);
 //    np.setMinValue(0);
 //    np.setFocusable(true);
 //    np.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
 //    np1.setMaxValue(9);
 //    np1.setMinValue(0);
 //    np1.setFocusable(true);
 //    np1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
 //   np2.setMaxValue(9);
 //    np2.setMinValue(0);
 //    np2.setFocusable(true);
 //     np2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         getload = getContext().getSharedPreferences("ir.lockscreen.ir", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

         ivLoader = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.vie);
          topvi = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.topview);
          int unspace = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.unlockspace);
          final float toplayotx = topvi.getX();
          final int toplayotwidth = (getScreenwidth()/2)-unspace;
         topvi.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()) {
             Boolean a = false ;
                @Override
                public void onSwipeRight(float dx) {
                    // Whatever
                    if (ViewHelper.getTranslationX(topvi)>(toplayotwidth))
                    {   a = true ;
                        }
                    else
                    ViewHelper.setTranslationX(topvi, topvi.getX() + dx);

                }

                @Override
                public void onup() {
                    // Whatever
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(a==true)
                    {ViewHelper.setTranslationX(topvi, getScreenwidth());
                    a=false;
                    endoflock();
                    }
                    else
                    ViewHelper.setTranslationX(topvi, toplayotx);

                }   


            });


         new AsyncCaller().execute();





    // np.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

    //  @Override
    //  public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //      if (newVal == 4)
    //      {
    //          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "shod", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //          Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SampleOverlayHideActivity.class);
    //          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //      getContext().startActivity(intent);
    //      }
    //  }
    //});

     */

}



 protected int getScreenwidth() {

     DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
     windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
     return width;
    }






@Override
protected void refreshViews() {
//  info.setText("WAITING\nWAITING");



}

@Override
protected void onTouchEvent_Up(MotionEvent event) {
    //info.setText("UP\nPOINTERS: " + event.getPointerCount());
}

@Override
protected void onTouchEvent_Move(MotionEvent event) {
//  info.setText("MOVE\nPOINTERS: " + event.getPointerCount());
}

@Override
protected void onTouchEvent_Press(MotionEvent event) {
    //info.setText("DOWN\nPOINTERS: " + event.getPointerCount());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent_LongPress() {
//  info.setText("LONG\nPRESS");

    return true;
}
```

and this is my xml to load view :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:showDividers="middle">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pl_message_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<!-- This FrameLayout is for proper divider drawing. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <me.zhanghai.patternlock.PatternView
        android:id="@+id/pl_pattern"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pl_button_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="12dp"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pl_left_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pl_right_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this error :

```
  06-04 10:26:43.363: W/ResourceType(1356): No package identifier when         getting value for resource number 0x00000000
  06-04 10:26:43.363: W/ResourceType(1356): No package identifier when       getting value for resource number 0x00000000
  06-04 10:26:43.363: W/ResourceType(1356): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
  06-04 10:26:43.363: W/ResourceType(1356): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
  06-04 10:26:43.367: W/ResourceType(1356): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
  06-04 10:26:43.375: D/AndroidRuntime(1356): Shutting down VM
  06-04 10:26:43.375: W/dalvikvm(1356): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c06648)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service ir.rn.lockscreen.Bestservice@52a5a95c with Intent {cmp=ir.rn.lockscreen/.Bestservice }: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class me.zhanghai.patternlock.PatternView
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at       android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2721)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at       android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class me.zhanghai.patternlock.PatternView
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at ir.rn.lockscreen.OverlayView.inflateView(OverlayView.java:96)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at ir.rn.lockscreen.OverlayView.load(OverlayView.java:143)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at ir.rn.lockscreen.OverlayView.<init>(OverlayView.java:62)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at ir.rn.lockscreen.PatternOverlayView.<init>(PatternOverlayView.java:112)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at ir.rn.lockscreen.Bestservice.onStartCommand(Bestservice.java:50)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2704)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   ... 10 more
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   ... 22 more
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at me.zhanghai.patternlock.PatternView.<init>(PatternView.java:299)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   at me.zhanghai.patternlock.PatternView.<init>(PatternView.java:260)
  06-04 10:26:43.391: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):   ... 25 more
```

when use patternview in activity and set theme to activity dont have problem , but when use in overlyview get error

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` in line 299 of `PatternView`, in its constructor.

Comment: i think this is for use style of patternview . 
Because when use style in activity no problem and no error .

Answer (score 1):

@Reza In my opinion you should include the following item in your theme by editing style.xml file :

<item name="patternViewStyle">@style/PatternView.Holo</item>

as mentioned by Zhang Hai here:
https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/PatternLock#styling

It worked for me. :)